# System.Runtime.Extensions requires a higher version of System.Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nuget, asp.net-core

I'm working on one of those new "Class Library (NuGet Package)" projects in Visual Studio. Everything was going fine until the other day it started raising an error about a `System.Runtime.Extensions` assembly:

```
Assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions' with identity 'System.Runtime.Extensions,
Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' uses 'System.Runtime,
Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher
version than referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime,
Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

I checked [on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Extensions/) and it appears indeed to be true, `System.Runtime.Extensions` requires `System.Runtime` to be at least 4.0.20.

I tried changing the following line in the `"dependencies"` section of my `project.json`:

```
"System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
```

to `"4.0.20-beta-23019"`, but then it tells me that "the type `IOException` exists in both `System.IO` and `System.Runtime`."

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks.

---

EDIT: Just tried this on a fresh new package project and it seems to be failing as well, so something's up.

Comment: It should be `4.0.20-beta-**23109**` not 23019. The numbers are extremely similar, but if you look at the version history, its slightly different: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime/

Comment: @RonBeyer Tried that, it gives me the second error I mentioned.

Comment: Where did you add this? In your global `dependencies` section or in a `dependencies` section of a .NET Core TFM? `dnxcore50` for example. It should only be added to .NET Core TFM's, because the full .NET framework references it by itself.

Comment: @HenkMollema I believe in the global section, I don't see any TFMs near it in the `project.json`. How do I put it in a TFM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was simply to explicitly specify my dependency on `System.Runtime.Extensions`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.0.0",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019"
},
```

And all that grief because I wanted to use `Environment.NewLine`. D'oh.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add it only to .NET Core target frameworks:

```
{
    "dependencies": { },

    "frameworks": {
        "dotnet": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0",
                "System.Collections": "4.0.10",
                "System.Linq": "4.0.0",
                "System.Runtime.Extensions": "4.0.10",
                "System.Threading": "4.0.10"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where `dnxcore50` is a .NET Core target framework. Could also be `dotnet` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just added the reference, though ([gist](https://gist.github.com/jamesqo/84cd638f346e0a193d2b)), and it's still giving out the same error.

Comment: @JamesKo I've updated my answer. Just add all the dependencies to `dotnet`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be giving me the second error I mentioned above... I'll open another question about this.